# Django CMS how to create nested plugins programatically

Tags: python, django, hyperlink, content-management-system, ckeditor

I am writing a migration script to parse an old html website into Django CMS pages.
The thing I need is to understand on how to nest plugins programatically.
In particular case I need to have html **< a>** tags converted into CMS LinkPlugin objects, nested inside text that is edited by standard ckeditor TextPlugin of Django-CMS.

How to programmatically nest plugins inside other plugins of Django CMS. In my case I need to nest a CMS Link plugin inside of the TextPlugin in the text. 
I know on how to parse text. I do not understand on how to do it from nested CMS plugins perspective?
I can not interconnect the Link CMS plugin object instance and CMSPlugin object instance that I insert into the ancestor TextPlugin.

More context:

Note I really know how to do this from UI perspective. I need to emulate this in a script.
I have dumped the database into JSON and noticed there are certain things there.

First I have a CMSPlugin class instance that is placed into a page placeholder. (Sotle this part from **placeholderadmin.py** of the CMS)

```
            position = CMSPlugin.objects.filter(language=lang, parent=parent).count()
            plugin = CMSPlugin(
                language='en',
                position=position,
                plugin_type=plugin_type,
                placeholder=placeholder,
            )
            plugin.insert_at(parent, position='last-child', save=False)
            plugin.save()

            # ?????
            plugin.link = Link(
                name='Link text',
                page_link=target_page,
                placeholder=placeholder,
            )
            plugin.save()
```

This creates a nested plugin in a proper placeholder and attaches it into a text plugin. However it is added with a blank LinkPlugin instance. I'm later creating an instance of a Link plugin in the CMS.
The thing is I do not know on how to do this properly.

From UI perspective the CMS plugin is added nested but contains no real plugin instance. SO the Admin plugins tree for that placeholder is rendered with empty Link plugins.
[image: Here how it looks]
CMSPlugins are added **Link** **< Empty>**.

I can edit this created Link plugin through admin and add a text and target link. How to do this programatically. E.g. inside of a script? Script must do 1000-s of pages so I can not do it manually

Answer (score 3):

Sorry just to be consistent on this. This is far more complicated in logic then it seems.
I did an article on this.

[Django CMS Adding plugins inside plugins programmatically](http://garmoncheg.blogspot.com/2015/01/django-cms-adding-plugins-inside.html)

In general the solution is to mimic the CMS way of doing this.

```
    # Getting an site admin instance
    admin_site = AdminSite()

    instance, plugin_admin = plugin.get_plugin_instance(admin_site)
    plugin_admin.cms_plugin_instance = plugin
    plugin_admin.placeholder = plugin.placeholder

    # Triggering the Django Admin add view with our request.
    # That's how Django-CMS does this action itself.
    response = plugin_admin.add_view(request)
```

Look for the full snippet in article. Hope this helps someone with similar problems.

Comment: I know this is an old answer but I'd like to point out that this solution will no longer work as of djangoCMS 3.3.0. The best way to add plugins programmatically is using the cms api (cms.api).

Answer (score 2):

To add nested plugins you need to do this:

```
        add_plugin(
            placeholder=placeholder,
            plugin_type='TextPlugin',
            language=translation.get_language(),
        )

        target = placeholder.get_plugins().get(plugin_type='TextPlugin')

        add_plugin(
            placeholder=placeholder, #same placeholder as the parent plugin
            plugin_type='LinkPlugin',
            language=translation.get_language(),
            target=target, #the parent plugin
            #here comes the params from the selected plugin
            name='Google',
            url='http://www.google.com'
        )
```

This also works with custom plugins.

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried to save Link plugin that you've created?

```
plugin.link = Link(
            name='Link text',
            page_link=target_page,
            placeholder=placeholder,
        )
```

maybe try to add

```
plugin.link.save()
```

I hope that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

To create nested plugins in your cms_plugins.py file

```
    from .models import ParentPlugin, ChildPlugin

    @plugin_pool.register_plugin
    class ParentCMSPlugin(CMSPluginBase):
    render_template = 'parent.html'
    name = 'Parent'
    model = ParentPlugin
    allow_children = True  # This enables the parent plugin to accept child plugins
    # You can also specify a list of plugins that are accepted as children,
    # or leave it away completely to accept all
    # child_classes = ['ChildCMSPlugin']

    def render(self, context, instance, placeholder):
        context = super().render(context, instance, placeholder)
        return context


@plugin_pool.register_plugin
class ChildCMSPlugin(CMSPluginBase):
    render_template = 'child.html'
    name = 'Child'
    model = ChildPlugin
    require_parent = True  # Is it required that this plugin is a child of another plugin?
    # You can also specify a list of plugins that are accepted as parents,
    # or leave it away completely to accept all
    # parent_classes = ['ParentCMSPlugin']

    def render(self, context, instance, placeholder):
        context = super(ChildCMSPlugin, self).render(context, instance, placeholder)
        return context
```

In your plugin template file of parent plugin

```
{% load cms_tags %}

<div class="plugin parent">
    {% for plugin in instance.child_plugin_instances %}
        {% render_plugin plugin %}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

For detailed documentation, go through

https://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/how_to/custom_plugins.html#nested-plugins